# How do I populate an array with foreach?

Tags: c#

How do I get the data I can write in the console to write to the array and the console.

At the moment it only displays on the console (not added functionality to add to array).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TBParser
{
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        String[] arr = new String[100];
        string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\ShpereCompare3.txt");
        Console.WriteLine("Contents of Text File: ");
        foreach (string line in lines)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\r\t" + line);

        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\Test.txt",lines);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Exit");
        Console.ReadKey();    
    }
   }
}
```

if my lines of text say

```
hello
my
name
is
Simon
```

then the first 5 slots of the array should contain each line?

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\ShpereCompare3.txt");
```

is already creating an array, each element of which contains one line.

There is no need to populate a new array with this same information via a `foreach`.

Comment: so how do i access it so i can use regular expressions to edit whats in the lines?

Comment: @simon you can apply regular expression on the variable 'line'

Comment: @KrishnaAnaril so i can write Center\W*\d*.\d+\W*mm within the array? i affectivly need to chop data out of multiple lines. so create a regular exression array then reference it in another array to write a different list out

Comment: @SimonGeorgeAndreou, make `arr` a `List<string>` and within your `foreach`, do something like `arr.Add(apply regex to line);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to copy the lines from the text file into another array, then you can do this:

```
String[] arr = new String[lines.Length];
Array.Copy(lines, arr, lines.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

found a work around. the path i was going down was too complicated. thanks for all your input

fixed code here

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TBParser
{
   class Program
   {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string fileName = @"C:shpereCompare3.txt";
        List<string> Names = new List<string>();
        List<string> Value = new List<string>();
        using (StreamReader fileReader = new StreamReader(fileName))
        {
            string fileLine;

            while (!fileReader.EndOfStream)
            {
                fileLine = fileReader.ReadLine();
                if (fileLine.StartsWith("Name"))
                {
                    Names.Add(fileLine.Substring(21));
                }
                if (fileLine.StartsWith("Center"))
                {
                    string[] fileSplit = fileLine.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    Value.Add(fileSplit[1]);
                }
            }
            string outputString = "";
            for (int i = 0;i < Names.Count; i++)
            {
                outputString += Names[i] + " = " + Value[i] + "\r\n";
            }
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"C:Test.txt", outputString);
        }
    }
}
```

}